# tiles will be clickable objects and when clicked they’ll open a separate page not in same page angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UeWe.png)

my app component code is

```
<H1>AI API DEMOS</H1>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li  class="active"><a routerLink="/market">Market Size</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a routerLink="/enrich">Enriched Tags</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a routerLink="/tbd">TBD</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a routerLink="/tbd">TBD</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a routerLink="/tbd">TBD</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a routerLink="/tbd">TBD</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

enrich.html:

```
<h1>enrich</h1>
```

desired output: when I click on "Enriched Tags" only and only enrich component HTML part should be display. no heading i.e. "AI API DEMOS" and unordered list of routing.

Comment: Did you give them the relevant page address in routing?

Comment: yes ```const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'enrich', component: PostComponent},
  { path : 'market' ,component: MarketComponent},
  { path: 'tbd' , component: TBDComponent }
]```    but heading and list are coming because its in main component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the heading and list to another component say `HomeComponent`. In `AppComponent` just keep `<router-outlet>`. And use routes like this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
    { path: 'enrich', component: PostComponent},
    { path : 'market', component: MarketComponent},
    { path: 'tbd', component: TBDComponent } 
]
```